# How is the WINE project financed?

Tags: wine, finance

Wine is a fantastic project and in my opinion it's speed of development is extremely fast. This must cost quite some resources, which I doubt is all done by volunteers. This makes me wonder: who are the major stakeholers in WINE, and who bears the brunt of the financial backing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many companies that support Wine. Here is a link to the FAQ on the Wine website that answers this question.

[Acknowledgements](http://wiki.winehq.org/Acknowledgements)

The Wine Project does a good job on this page stating how they were supported by the various companies listed

Even the companies that may not give direct financial support can provide just as valuable support by adding code that improves the Wine project.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of all the details, but codeweavers provide a lot of support for wine.

Have a look at [this link](http://www.codeweavers.com/about/support_wine) for more details

Answer (score 1):

WINE project is financed by users and Codeweavers is the major contributor of Wine. You can read it on their website : http://www.winehq.org/about/